# When page is not node entity site breaks

Tags: 8, nodes

How can correct this, my problem is that I'm using node label to set class. And everything works perfectly until I visit contact form or user login form which are not node entities, then site completely breaks, only on that two pages. How can I make some condition if it's not node or its contact form?

```
  if ($vars['node']->getType('location')) {
    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    $title = $node->label();
    $vars['location'] = str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($title));
  }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are loading the node object again?

Answer (score 4):

`getType()` takes no arguments.

What you want to do is:

```
  if (isset($vars['node']) && $vars['node']->getType() == 'location') {
    $title = $vars['node']->label();
    $vars['location'] = str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($title));
  }
```

That will check that the node object exists in the variables array, and getType returns location.

You could go a step further and ensure the type on the off chance that $vars['node'] could get set to anything not an instance of NodeInterface, which getType would not be available for and throw another error.

```
  if (isset($vars['node']) && ($vars['node'] instanceof NodeInterface) && $vars['node']->getType() == 'location') {
    $title = $vars['node']->label();
    $vars['location'] = str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($title));
  }
```

Be sure to include `NodeInterface` with a `use` statement at the top of the file.

See more about [getType()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21Entity%21Node.php/function/Node%3A%3AgetType/8.2.x).

Comment: `$route_match = \Drupal::routeMatch();
  if ($route_match->getRouteName() == 'entity.node.canonical') {
    if ($vars['node']->getType('location')) {
      $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
      $title = $node->label();
      $vars['location'] = str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($title));
    }
  }` Thanks a lot for help Kevin, appreciate it . Also kinda manage to solve with checking if a current page is a node.

Comment: Well, if `routeMatch` returns nothing on a non node page like Contact or User, then it can still break. I wasn't sure why you were calling for node again.

Comment: Btw I've tried both your answer it still breaks. But with the example, I supplied it works.

Comment: I feel like because you're using a node object in a variables array, and then proceeding to use a node object from the current request - when you may not always be on a node path, and then calling a method on a null object.